# Getting error message "No accounts with iTunes Connect access" though having Admin role to that team

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, account, application-loader

I know this question is asked many times but no solution worked for me .
I have already logged in Xcode preference - accounts tab. My role is "Admin". Still I am unable to upload ipa to App store from Organizer window - Archives. I am getting error message "No accounts with iTunes Connect access. iTunes Connect access for 'Team-Name' is required. Add an account in the Accounts preference pane".

I already tried removing and adding my account to Xcode preference - accounts. I have all the provisioning profiles required and certificates in my Keychain Access. Event 2 or 3 days back I was able to upload ipa through Organizer window - Archives.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to upload using Application loaded, but it failed showing messege "ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version." But previous uploaded ipa ( in a state ready for sale and newest in testflight)has Version 2.7 , build 1.5 and current ipa which I am trying to upload has Version 2.7 , build 1.6. What should I do now?

Comment: Well I think for now it is not possible to upload app to iTunes Connect through XCODE. I don't know the reason. The only possible way is  Application Loader. It worked for me when I increased the version number in App Store because latest version of my app in App Store was in Ready for Sale state.